# Matlab Error - Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'table'

Tags: matlab, matrix

I tried to add element of table to scalar("summ=summ+el;" line), but I got an error:

> Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'table'.

Here's code:

```
j=1;
el=0.;
fin=zeros([218,2]);
for i=1:545000
if mod(i,2500)==0
    summ=summ * 0.0004;
    fin(j,1)=res(i,2);
    fin(j,2)=summ;
    j=j+1;
    summ=0;
end
    el=res000(i,3);
summ=summ+el;
end
plot(fin);
```

**res** and **res000** are 545000x4 and 545000x3 tables accordingly.

Comment: `summ=summ+table2array(el);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need